# blender pip whl module install issue

Tags: python, pydev, blender

I have 2 pythons on my computer
One for eclipse and other applications and one for blender.
Computer python version here:

> **C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts**

Blender (2.79) version is here:

> **C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\bin**

I installed pip for Blender (I hope I did) and it is here:

**C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib\site-packages\pip**

Then I do this in CMD:

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib\site-packages>**pip install C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\pydevd-1.3.2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl**

And get this:

> Installing collected packages: pydevd
>     Found existing installation: pydevd 1.3.0
>       Uninstalling pydevd-1.3.0:
>         Successfully uninstalled pydevd-1.3.0
>     The script pydevd.exe is installed in 'c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
>     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
>   Successfully installed pydevd-1.3.2

But I get this error still in my script under Blender:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\emamili\Documents\Posao\modeli\blendtest.blend\Run.py", line 9,

in

```
pydev.debug(SCRIPT, PYDEVD_PATH)
```

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\pydev_debug.py", line 25, in

debug
    **import pydevd**

> ImportError: No module named 'pydevd'
>    Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...

Answer (score 1):

Your `pip` seems to be installing it to:

`c:\users\xxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\` (which is in your `Installing collected packages` message).

`pip` is probably mapping to your `pip` inside `python35-32\scripts\pip.exe` and by being inside the `blender\site-packages` doesn't change that.

Search for your `pip.exe` inside `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python` or execute the `python` from blender with `python -m pip install pydevd`.

Comment: I did that, thnx, installed pip in blender too.